# How to write python polyglot unittest for method using type function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, unit-testing

I am trying to write python2 and python3 compatible code which uses type function. Both return different strings in 2 v/s 3, which I have to assert in my unit tests.

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Oct 18 2019, 15:58:40)
>>> type(2)
<class 'int'>

Python 2.7.16 (default, Jul 24 2019, 16:45:12)
>>> type(2)
<type 'int'>
```

The intention here is to validate the exception messages raised from my function. For example,

```
def func(arg1):
    if not isinstance(arg1, int):
        raise TypeError('Expected type %s but got %s' % (type(int), type(arg1)))
        
    print("Function executed")
    
try:
    func('str')
except TypeError as e:
    assert e.args[0]== "Expected type <type 'type'> but got <type 'str'>"
    print("Correct exception was raised")
```

Assertion here passes in python2 but fails in python3.

Comment: Why check the string representations of the types at all?

Comment: @AbhinavGupta Does my answer help you?

Comment: @Davis I have updated my question for better clarity. Please have a re-look. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I ran the code and got this error message `AttributeError: 'TypeError' object has no attribute 'message'` in python 3. This is because the attribute `message` from errors has been deprecated since python 2.6 according to: https://github.com/google/yapf/issues/564 It has been deprecated since python 2.6 and to look to: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0352/ for further information. It seems like using `e.message` will not allow for the code to work in both versions.

Comment: @Eno Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the line to be compatible with both versions.

Answer (score 2):

Variations like this are the motivation for the [`assertRaisesRegexp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaisesRegex) function from the standard `unittest` module (which you should probably be using).  (Note the spelling: Python 3 supports the only spelling from 2 (with the `p`), so that’s what you’d want here.)

Comment: Thanks @Davis, this is what I was looking for. However, I've decided to wrap the error and override the message string for now. It would require simple changes in the unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Using `type()` in python for almost anything is not flexible. Instead you should use `isinstance(var, type)`. It is almost the same in both versions of python 2.7 and 3:

```
isinstance(2, int)
```

This returns True in both versions every time.

Make sure you do not accidentally put the type in a string:

INCORRECT: `'int'`

CORRECT: `int`

OR:

`print(type(2) is int)`

will output:

`True`

Comment: Hi @Eno, I have updated my question. Can you please have a re-look? Thanks for helping out :)

Comment: Yes sure I will update my answer as soon as I find out a solution with this new information you have provided.